# how to save file to model from outside with carrierwave?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, file-upload, carrierwave

I have model:

```
class RealtyPhoto < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :photo

  mount_uploader :photo, RealtyPhotoUploader

  belongs_to :realty_object
end
```

And uploader:

```
class RealtyPhotoUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

  include CarrierWave::RMagick

  storage :file

  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end

  def default_url
    [version_name, "/assets/default-flat.jpg"].compact.join('_')
  end

  def extension_white_list
    %w(jpg jpeg gif png)
  end
end
```

I write in my code something like this:

```
require 'open-uri'

object = RealtyObject.last

photo = RealtyPhoto.new

photo.photo = open('http://milushov.ru/bg.jpg').read

object.realty_photos << photo
```

And i get an error on that line:

```
 photo.photo = open('http://milushov.ru/bg.jpg').read
ArgumentError: string contains null byte
from /home/roma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@miel/gems/carrierwave-0.7.1/lib/carrierwave/sanitized_file.rb:113:in `expand_path'
```

Does anybody know how to download and save file from outside? (when i save file from form on the page - all ok). Maybe using CarrierWave Uploader?

Comment: may be encoding or try to save in file and check

Comment: photo.remote_photo_url = "url" try this

Comment: @Amar, yes, it's works! Thank you! Write this as answer and i will choose you :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Carrierwave upload image from remote url using `remote_column_name_url` in your case
`photo.remote_photo_url = "url"`

Answer (score 2):

You seemed to have forgotten to close the file handle. Closing the file will likely make your application work correctly.

Answer (score 1):

you could also do it in another way.. 
more efficient is 
    model[:name] = filename
    model.save
    surl = model.photo.url
    FileUtils.copy(filesrc,surl,derefrence=true)

this approach basically saves you from copying the file to one location and ten copying it to another location when saved